# Hadoop -copyFromLocal cant find the destination

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I try to copy file from local to hadoop file system...
I'm using single node cluster

```
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /usr/hduser

hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ hadoop fs -ls

Found 1 items

drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 18:33 sample

hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ cd Documents

hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ ls

file  hadoopFIle.txt  URICat  URICat.java

hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ cd

hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Documents/file /usr/local/hadoop

copyFromLocal: `/usr/local/hadoop': No such file or directory
```

I am getting this error message, please help me with this problem.

Comment: should it be ~/Documents/file ?

Comment: hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ~/Documents/file /usr/local/hadoop
copyFromLocal: `/usr/local/hadoop': No such file or directory
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ~/Documents/file /usr/local/hadoop
copyFromLocal: `/usr/local/hadoop': No such file or directory

Comment: verify that /usr/local/hadoop exists and is writeable

Comment: hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ cd /usr/local/hadoop
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$  It exists i created simple dir hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop fs -ls
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 18:33 sample
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$

Comment: I think you are getting confused with local file system and hadoop file system . The path you are pointing seems to be local file system path , because you cannot do cd on hadoop file system path . You may paste the output of /usr/local/hadoop by running : hadoop fs  -ls /usr/local/hadoop

Comment: yes i cant use cd in hadoop file system.... I tried to copy the local file into hadoop file system.

Comment: When I'm inside the destination folder I can copy the file
**hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ cd /usr/local/hadoop
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ~/Documents/file file
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop fs -ls
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup         81 2015-03-12 15:46 file
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop fs -cat file
this is the first file
try to runn the hadoop file from the single node cluster.
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$**
when I'm out of it. I can't copy the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try this command.

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

if it is listing out the local file system files.(not hdfs),then try

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://IP-ADDRESS-of your-machine/
```

now copy your file to hdfs by

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Documents/file  hdfs://Ip-addressofyourmachine/above result path
```

Comment: hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 3 items
drwx------   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 18:40 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 18:23 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 19:21 /usr hduser@jothinathan-:~$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/
Found 3 items
drwx------   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 18:40 hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 18:23 hdfs://localhost:9000/user
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-03-10 19:21 hdfs://localhost:9000/usr

Comment: The Same message hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Documents/file hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hadoop
copyFromLocal: `hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hadoop': No such file or directory

Comment: there is no  /local/hadoop path in your   hdfs   /usr/  path . first create  a directory.    hadoop  fs  -mkdir   hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local

Comment: NO I can go inside the hadoop path from the terminal hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:~$ cd /usr/local/hadoop
hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$

Comment: i can list the file in side the hadoop folder hduser@jothinathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ ls
bin  etc  include  lib  libexec  LICENSE.txt  logs  NOTICE.txt  README.txt  sbin  share

Comment: First thing is  the local file system is different from hdfs file system.  you can acess hdfs file system through url of hdfs.  you cant  fire cd commands on hdfs.   /usr/local/hadoop  is in local file system